# Why can't interaction be measured with a complete block design?

Tags: interaction, experiment-design, blocking

I am struggling to understand why interaction cannot be measured in a CBD. While many sources say it is because there is only one observation per block/treatment combination, could you not compare the different response values for each level of the treatment within a block compared to that of another block, and be able to discern that the block has an effect on how the levels effect the response value observed?

Comment: What sources say that an interaction cannot be estimated with a CBD?